# copying contents of a text file in c

Tags: c, file-io, standard-library

I want to read a text file and transfer it's contents to another text file in c, Here is my code:

```
             char buffer[100]; 

             FILE*  rfile=fopen ("myfile.txt","r+");
             if(rfile==NULL)
            {
              printf("couldn't open File...\n");
            }


            fseek(rfile, 0, SEEK_END);
            size_t file_size = ftell(rfile);
            printf("%d\n",file_size);
            fseek(rfile,0,SEEK_SET);
            fread(buffer,file_size,1,rfile);


            FILE* pFile = fopen ( "newfile.txt" , "w+" );
            fwrite (buffer , 1 ,sizeof(buffer) , pFile );
            fclose(rfile);
            fclose (pFile);
            return 0;
          }
```

the problem that I am facing is the appearence of unnecessary data in the receiving file,
I tried the fwrite function with both "sizeof(buffer)" and "file_size",In the first case it is displaying greater number of useless characters while in the second case the number of useless characters is only 3,I would really appreciate if someone pointed out my mistake and told me how to get rid of these useless characters...

Comment: Most files are  bigger than 100 bytes long. Therefore, you need to read the file in chunks to avoid buffer overflow.  I'd user a bigger buffer size (like 4096 or even 65536 bytes), and iterate on that.  The other advice in the answers about paying attention to the order of the arguments to `fread()` and the return value are also correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your are writing all the content of `buffer` (100 char) in the receiving file. You need to write the exact amount of data read.

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, file_size, pFile)
```

Adding more checks for your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE   100

int main(void) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    size_t file_size;
    size_t ret;

    FILE* rfile = fopen("input.txt","r+");
    if(rfile==NULL)
    {
      printf("couldn't open File \n");
      return 0;
    }

    fseek(rfile, 0, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(rfile);
    fseek(rfile,0,SEEK_SET);

    printf("File size: %d\n",file_size);

    if(!file_size) {
        printf("Warring! Empty input file!\n");
    } else if( file_size >= BUFFER_SIZE ){
        printf("Warring! File size greater than %d. File will be truncated!\n", BUFFER_SIZE);
        file_size = BUFFER_SIZE;
    }

    ret = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), file_size, rfile);
    if(file_size != ret) {
        printf("I/O error\n");
    } else {
        FILE* pFile = fopen ( "newfile.txt" , "w+" );
        if(!pFile) {
            printf("Can not create the destination file\n");
        } else {
            ret = fwrite (buffer , 1 ,file_size , pFile );
            if(ret != file_size) {
                printf("Writing error!");
            }
            fclose (pFile);
        }
    }
    fclose(rfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes I've tried with file_size but it reduces the number of useless characters not eliminates them...@Bechir

Comment: @AaymanKhalid, which can be because the fread() did not read everything. Check its return value.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant,I checked the value of fread and indeed is "zero":(

Comment: @AaymanKhalid Please note that you are opening the input file with the option `r+`. If the file `myfile.txt` doesn't exist, it will be created with zero data length. That could explain why you are reading zero size data.

Comment: @Bechir,the file does exist,otherwise I'll get the error"couldn't open file",and the data is copied too,it's the useless characters I don't want in the newfile...

Comment: @AaymanKhalid I updated my answer to add more checks. Shall give you a hint why you have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the return values from all calls to `fseek()`, `fread()` and `fwrite()`, even `fclose()`.

In your example, you have `fread()` read 1 block which is 100 bytes long. It's often a better idea to reverse the parameters, like this:  `ret = fread(buffer,1,file_size,rfile)`. The `ret` value will then show how many bytes it could read, instead of just saying it could not read a full block.

Comment: @AaymanKhalid, excellent. Then you can create a loop around your reads and writes, which keeps reading and writing until `feof(rfile)` is set. (Or until you have read file_size bytes, if you trust the file not to change.) If you use `feof(rfile)`, you don't really need to know how large the file is in total, your loop will copy until the end of the file. (This can even avoid trouble with very very large files, but that is another story...)

Comment: @ Amigable Clark Kant,Thank you so much:)

Comment: and one more thing,could you explain to me why there is a difference between the file size and the size of the data read from the file?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid, the operating system has the right to read as little as it wants. It does not *have* to use all the buffer space you give it.  In extreme cases it can even read 0 bytes, but read more at next call. Therefore, always check feof()

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of an (almost) general purpose file copy function:

```
void fcopy(FILE *f_src, FILE *f_dst)
{
    char            buffer[BUFSIZ];
    size_t          n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f_src)) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, f_dst) != n)
            err_syserr("write failed\n");
    }
}
```

Given an open file stream `f_src` to read and another open file stream `f_dst` to write, it copies (the remainder of) the file associated with `f_src` to the file associated with `f_dst`.  It does so moderately economically, using the buffer size `BUFSIZ` from `<stdio.h>`.  Often, you will find that bigger buffers (such as 4 KiB or 4096 bytes, even 64 KiB or 65536 bytes) will give better performance.  Going larger than 64 KiB seldom yields much benefit, but YMMV.

The code above calls an error reporting function (`err_syserr()`) which is assumed not to return.  That's why I designated it 'almost general purpose'.  The function could be upgraded to return an `int` value, 0 on success and EOF on a failure:

```
enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 4096 };

int fcopy(FILE *f_src, FILE *f_dst)
{
    char            buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t          n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), f_src)) > 0)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, f_dst) != n)
            return EOF;  // Optionally report write failure
    }
    if (ferror(f_src) || ferror(f_dst))
        return EOF;  // Optionally report I/O error detected
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this design doesn't open or close files; it works with open file streams.  You can write a wrapper that opens the files and calls the copy function (or includes the copy code into the function).  Also note that to change the buffer size, I simply changed the buffer definition; I didn't change the main copy code.  Also note that any 'function call overhead' in calling this little function is completely swamped by the overhead of the I/O operations themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Note `ftell` returns a `long`, not a `size_t`. Shouldn't matter here, though. `ftell` itself is not necessarily a byte-offset, though. The standard requires it only to be an acceptable argument to `fseek`. You might get a better result from `fgetpos`, but it has the same portability issue from the lack of specification by the standard. (Confession: I didn't check the standard itself; got all this from the manpages.)

The more robust way to get a file-size is with `fstat`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd>

struct stat stat_buf;
if (fstat(filename, &buf) == -1)
    perror(filename), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
file_size = statbuf.st_size;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameters you passed in the fwrite are not in right sequence.

To me it should be like that-

fwrite(buffer,SIZE,1,pFile)

as the syntax of fwrite is 
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

The function fwrite() writes nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the  location given by ptr.

So change the sequence and try again.